# Place navigation bar at bottom of header

Tags: html, css, replace, header, navigation

I have made a navigation bar which functions as I want it to, the only problem is that the bar is placed on the top of my black header, where I would like it to be placed at the bottom of the header. How do I fix this?

My code (html):

```
<div id="navBarTop">
        <ul>
                <li><a href="test">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">Test</a></li>
                <li><a href="test">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

My code (css):

```
    #navBarTop {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFB700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
}

#navBarTop ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0; 
    margin-left: 350px;
}

#navBarTop li {
    float: left; 
}

#navBarTop li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    color: #4c4c4c;
    border-right: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
}

#navBarTop li a:hover {
    background-color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `position: relative` on parent div and `position: absolute` with `bottom: 0` on navigation div.

checkout fiddle for solution: http://jsfiddle.net/pctdwz1f/

```
 .header{
    background:#000;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
} 
#navBarTop {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFB700;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: Only problem is that there is still a black border at the bottom, it has to be all the way at the bottom of that.

Comment: that is because of bottom margin on navigation div. I have updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pctdwz1f/1/